# Running Query inside WHILE/Loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

Need help here, got a query that counts number of rows for each member and emails it to them.

So right now they get a simple email telling them how many posts they have, I have searched for a way to run a second query inside the main query (which counts the posts from the post table, generates the email based on their account info in another table) What we want is to have the email show each post as well, I am already joining tables in my first query and I can't seem to find a way to run a second inside the while statement.

Here is the code we currently have. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(localhost, xxxxxxx, xxxxxxxx);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(systm_test);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}
$count = 0; 
$date = date("Y-m-d", $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
$day = date("l F jS, Y", $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);

$qry= sprintf("SELECT p.tech, p.date, e.email, e.fullname, "
            . "COUNT( * ) AS record_count "
            . "FROM users_test AS e "
            . "JOIN sc AS p ON e.tech = p.tech "
            . "WHERE DATE = '%s' "
            . "GROUP BY p.tech, e.fullname, e.email, p.date",
          $date
      );

$result = mysql_query($qry); 

if (!$result) { 
    # something went wrong... 
    error_log(sprintf('%d: %s', mysql_errno(), mysql_error())); 
    echo 'Unable to retrieve callpost report';

} else { 

    while ($node = mysql_fetch_object($result)) { 



        $headers = "From: xxxxxxxxxx <noreply@xxxxx.xxx>\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "X-Priority: 1 (Higuest)\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Importance: High\r\n"; 

        $subject = sprintf('%s | Post Report', $node->fullname); 

            $date = date("Y-m-d", $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);


        $body = sprintf( 
            'Dear %s, <br><br> 
            Your daily post report for %s. 
            <br> 
            <br>     
            System Info<br> 
            ------------------------------------<br> 
            Member Id:      <b>%d</b><br> 
            Posts:      <b>%d</b>
            <br>
            System Name:    TEST<br>', 

            $node->fullname, 
            $day, 
            $node->tech, 
            $node->record_count 
        ); 

        if (!mail($node->email, $subject, $body, $headers)) 
        { 
            error_log( 
                sprintf('failed sending email report to %s (%d)', 
                    $node->fullname, 
                    $node->tech) 
            ); 
        } 
    } //end while statement 
     mail($node->email, $subject, $body, $headers);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: In general, you should mention the database you're using (and it's often helpful to have the version, as well)

Answer (score 0):

A sub-select is what your looking for.  Something like.

```
"SELECT p.tech, p.date, e.email, e.fullname, "
        . "COUNT( * ) AS record_count, "
        . "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts z WHERE z.author = e.tech) as post_count "
        . "FROM users_test AS e "
        . "JOIN sc AS p ON e.tech = p.tech "
        . "WHERE DATE = '%s' "
        . "GROUP BY p.tech, e.fullname, e.email, p.date"
```